# sound.seek() doesn't. Nothing happens. I wanna to make an easy mp3player for my application

Tags: python, kivy

`sound.seek()` doesn't. Nothing happens. Sound position always is 0. I wanna to make an easy mp3player for my application. How can i make it work correctly. When I move a slider label.text and sound position also should move. And when music is playing slider cursor should move too. This is my code:

```
def to_seconds(value):
    a_string = str(int(value // 60))
    b_string = str(int(value % 60))
    if len(a_string) == 1:
        a_string = '0' + a_string
    if len(b_string) == 1:
        b_string = '0' + b_string
    return a_string + ' : ' + b_string


class Player(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.file = 'music_files/Billie_Eilish_-_Ocean_Eyes.mp3'
        self.play = 'images/play.png'
        self.palki = 'images/palki.png'
        self.cursor = 'images/cursor.png'
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load(self.file)
        print(to_seconds(self.sound.length))
        self.sl = Slider(orientation='horizontal',
                     min=0,
                     max=self.sound.length,
                     step=1,
                     padding=20,
                     background_width=40,
                     value_track=True,
                     value_track_color=(1, .1, .1, 1),
                     value_track_width=(5),
                     cursor_image=(self.cursor),
                     value=self.sound.get_pos()
                     )
        self.sl.bind(value=self.slider_callback)
        self.w1.add_widget(self.sl)

        but1 = Button()
        self.but2 = Button(background_normal=(self.play),
                       background_down=(self.play),
                       on_press=self.play_but_callback
                       )
        but3 = Button()


        self.gl.add_widget(but1)
        self.gl.add_widget(self.but2)
        self.gl.add_widget(but3)


        self.lb = Label(font_size=35,
                    size_hint_x=.85,
                    text=to_seconds(self.sl.value),
                    halign='right',
                    valign='top'
                    )
        self.al.add_widget(self.lb)
        self.sl.value = self.sound.get_pos()
        self.sound.play()

    def slider_callback(self, intance, value):
        print(value)
        if self.sound:
            self.sound.play()
            self.sound.seek(int(value))

        print(self.sound.get_pos())
        self.lb.text = to_seconds(value)
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html#kivy.core.audio.Sound.seek), `Most sound providers cannot seek when the audio is stopped. Play then seek`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I've tried like that  but doesn't work

Comment: Methods seek and get_pos does not work. In module seek passes, get_pos returns 0

Comment: Seems like that should work. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The `Sound` class is just the base class that is extended by the audio providers. The `Soundloader.load()` should return one of those provider classes that over-rides `get_pos` and `seek`. In the log that Python produces, there should be some mention of `audio` and/or `Sound`. That should indicate which audio provider is being used.